# Regex: Finding all line breaks without an " as previous character

Tags: regex, line-breaks, textwrangler

I have a file with a bunch of data looking like this:

```
"sc14b61ecf5ef162","sc14b61b07ba1690","1264806000","1264806000","780","1080","Navn arrangement:
Dørene åpner:
Arr.start:
Arr:slutt:
Dørene stenger:
HA (navn):
HA (tlf):
Type arrangement: (her: om konsert, gjerne sjanger)
Forvetet antall gjester:"
"sc14b61f9e35f569","sc14b61bf07647db","1265583600","1265583600","1020","1260","Nord/Sør
Foredrag
Ønsker skjenking"
```

This repeats itself many times (with different data). I would like it to look like this:

```
"sc14b61ecf5ef162","sc14b61b07ba1690","1264806000","1264806000","780","1080","Navn arrangement:Dørene åpner:Arr.start:Arr:slutt:Dørene stenger:HA (navn):HA (tlf):Type arrangement: (her: om konsert, gjerne sjanger)Forvetet antall gjester:"
"sc14b61f9e35f569","sc14b61bf07647db","1265583600","1265583600","1020","1260","Nord/Sør Foredrag Ønsker skjenking"
```

I think that what I need is some way to remove all line-breaks that does not have an " in front of it, but my regex is weak.

I'm using Textwrangler (the text editor for OS X).

Answer (score 3):

This is called [negative look behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). This should do the trick.

```
(?<!")\n
```

Per @ax in the comments, on a Mac, you may need to change the `\n` to `\r` like so:

```
(?<!")\r
```

If that still doesnt work, sometimes you may need to combine the two:

```
(?<!")\r\n
```

One of these should meet your needs.

Comment: on a mac, this would be `(?<!")\r`

Comment: ive never had problems with just \n but youre right. Some programs or OSes also do \r\n

Comment: for textwrangler on os x, it most probably is only `\r`: see this screenshot: http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/textwranglerpower.html

Comment: oh well: the newline representation for OS X is LF, \n: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations

Comment: I know on windows, I have seen applications go any of these ways. I assumed Mac would be similar but I have never looked into it enough to test.